# The length of the row clustering object is not the same as the number of matrix rows

Tags: r, visualization, heatmap

I want to plot a heatmap using `ComplexHeatmap`. The rows are clustered based on `cluster$clust`

```
library(ComplexHeatmap)

plotdata <- list(met.resolv.immune)

annRow <- rownames(met.resolv.immune)

colvec <- clust.col[1:length(unique(cluster$clust))]
names(colvec) <- paste0("KIRP ",unique(cluster$clust))
annCol <- annCol[colnames(plotdata[[1]]), , drop = FALSE]
annCol$Subtype <- paste0("KIRP ",cluster[colnames(plotdata[[1]]),"clust"])
annColors[["Subtype"]] <- colvec

clust.dist.row <- "pearson"
clust.method.row <- "ward.D"

ha <- ComplexHeatmap::HeatmapAnnotation(df=annCol, col=annColors,border=FALSE)
legend.name <- "M value"
row.title <- "Methylation"

fig.path <- getwd()
fig.name <- "Plots/KIRP_immunomethylomics_methylresolver"

n_dat <- length(plotdata)

hcg <- hclust(ClassDiscovery::distanceMatrix(as.matrix(t(plotdata[[i]])), clust.dist.row[i]), clust.method.row[i])
rowlab <- intersect(rownames(plotdata[[i]]),annRow[[i]])
rowlab.index <- match(rowlab, rownames(plotdata[[i]]))
plotdata <- lapply(plotdata, function(x) x[cluster$samID,])

#col_fun = circlize::colorRamp2(1, meth.col[[i]])
ht <-  ComplexHeatmap::Heatmap(matrix               = as.matrix(plotdata[[i]]),
                               row_title            = row.title[i],
                               name                 = legend.name[i],
                               cluster_columns      = FALSE,
                               cluster_rows         = hcg,
                               show_column_dend     = FALSE,
                               show_column_names    = FALSE,
                               show_row_dend        = TRUE,
                               show_row_names       = FALSE,
                               col                  = meth.col[[i]],
                               top_annotation       = switch((i == 1) + 1, NULL, ha),
                               width                = grid::unit(width, "cm"),
                               height               = grid::unit(height, "cm"),
                               heatmap_legend_param = list(at        = c(0, 1),
                                                           legend_gp = grid::gpar(fill = meth.col),
                                                           labels    = c("0", "1")),
                               right_annotation     = ComplexHeatmap::rowAnnotation(link =
                                                                                      anno_mark(at         = rowlab.index,
                                                                                                labels     = rowlab,
                                                                                                which      = "row",
                                                                                                lines_gp   = grid::gpar(fontsize = 5),
                                                                                                link_width = grid::unit(3, "mm"),
                                                                                                padding    = grid::unit(0.8, "mm"),
                                                                                                labels_gp  = grid::gpar(fontsize = 7))))
outFile <- file.path(fig.path,paste0(fig.name,".pdf"))
if(is.null(annCol)) {
  pdf(outFile, width = width, height = height * n_dat/2)
} else {
  pdf(outFile, width = width, height = height * n_dat/1.5)
}
draw(ht, merge_legend = TRUE, heatmap_legend_side = "right") # output to pdf
```

Traceback:

```
Error: The length of the row clustering object is not the same as the number of matrix
rows.
```

Desired heatmap layout:

[image]

Data:

```
> dput(clust.col)
c(CS2a = "#e784ba", CS1a = "#80e8dd", CS1b = "#7cc2f6", CS2b = "#f9c1a0", 
CS1c = "#af81e4", CS2c = "#b7f6af")

> dput(cluster$clust[1:10])
c("2a", "1a", "1b", "1a", "1a", "1b", "2b", "2b", "2a", "1a")


> dput(met.resolv.immune[,1:10])
structure(list(TCGA.2K.A9WE.01A = c(-0.0149649503030302, 0.0455124278204717, 
-0.0149649503030302, 0.0422339581471679, -0.0149649503030302, 
0.0031603286817658, -0.0031167647829944, -0.0149649503030302, 
-0.0149649503030302, -0.00769638965290758, -0.00526880869835241
), TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01A = c(-0.0128430175757575, -0.0128430175757575, 
0.0950520724265595, 0.0067089371546907, -0.0128430175757575, 
-0.0101733808064506, -0.00694046712078601, -0.0128430175757575, 
-0.0122519440837071, -0.0128430175757575, -0.00818012969151895
), TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01A = c(-0.0140913757575757, 0.0317656796259015, 
0.00530609451526296, -0.0140913757575757, -0.0140913757575757, 
-0.0140913757575757, -0.00622764890293931, -0.0140913757575757, 
0.0342384997710695, -0.0140913757575757, 0.0194656295361599), 
    TCGA.2Z.A9J5.01A = c(-0.0148366566666666, 0.0370367065064792, 
    -0.00890344608673003, 0.0365524237907845, -0.0115635952096826, 
    -0.00031740806825907, 0.00243205790204093, -0.0148366566666666, 
    -0.0148366566666666, -0.0131812037616607, 0.00245443492702743
    ), TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01A = c(-0.014808596060606, 0.0313861000288843, 
    0.00271634111707363, 0.0433197835668216, -0.014808596060606, 
    -0.00638823087831103, 0.00386361103106003, -0.014808596060606, 
    -0.014808596060606, -0.0118747005482477, -0.00378852007485697
    ), TCGA.2Z.A9J7.01A = c(-0.0153730130303029, 0.000764514367146384, 
    0.0269731921561654, 0.0469744027206741, -0.0153730130303029, 
    -0.0142064773309012, -0.00849800941704341, -0.0153730130303029, 
    0.00338396020149058, -0.0153730130303029, 0.00610046942367988
    ), TCGA.2Z.A9J8.01A = c(-0.0135451406060605, -0.0135451406060605, 
    0.102508162132096, 0.0106658648709085, -0.0135451406060605, 
    -0.0135451406060605, -0.0108800518564085, -0.0135451406060605, 
    -0.0118799805034039, -0.0135451406060605, -0.00914315100682858
    ), TCGA.2Z.A9JD.01A = c(-0.00840480242424243, 0.0123991501125572, 
    -0.00840480242424243, -0.00840480242424243, 0.00430748973013917, 
    0.0189004073728262, -0.00840480242424243, -0.00222501742515534, 
    0.0170467847550874, -0.00840480242424243, -0.00840480242424243
    ), TCGA.2Z.A9JI.01A = c(-0.00885515484848484, 0.000457879445022963, 
    0.0327954618120268, -0.00885515484848484, 0.0178182058872652, 
    -0.00885515484848484, 0.010914536795079, -0.00885515484848484, 
    -0.00885515484848484, -0.00885515484848484, -0.00885515484848484
    ), TCGA.2Z.A9JJ.01A = c(-0.0149310384848484, 0.0449108689187918, 
    -0.0149310384848484, 0.0541321639781085, -0.0149310384848484, 
    -0.00762182284381627, -0.00731084249587843, -0.0149310384848484, 
    -0.00724661545813282, -0.0149310384848484, -0.00220855967483088
    )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("Monocytes", "Dendritic Cells", 
"Macrophages", "Neutrophils", "Eosinophils", "Regulatory T cells", 
"Naive T cells", "Memory T cells", "CD8 T cells", "NK cells", 
"B cells"))

> dput(annCol[1:10,])
structure(list(race = c("white", "white", "white", "white", "white", 
"white", "white", "white", "white", "white"), gender = c("male", 
"male", "male", "male", "male", "male", "male", "male", "male", 
"female"), age = c(53, 71, 67, 80, 60, 63, 50, 66, 38, 69), pstage = c("stage ii", 
"stage i", "stage ii", "stage ii", "stage i", "stage iv", "stage i", 
"stage i", "stage iii", "stage i"), Subtype = c("KIRP 2a", "KIRP 1a", 
"KIRP 1b", "KIRP 1a", "KIRP 1a", "KIRP 1b", "KIRP 2b", "KIRP 2b", 
"KIRP 2a", "KIRP 1a")), row.names = c("TCGA.2K.A9WE.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9J1.01A", 
"TCGA.2Z.A9J3.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9J5.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9J6.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9J7.01A", 
"TCGA.2Z.A9J8.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9JD.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9JI.01A", "TCGA.2Z.A9JJ.01A"
), class = "data.frame")

> dput(annColors)
list(race = c(white = "#FDEFE5", `black or african american` = "#3D0C02", 
`american indian or alaska native` = "#CC9A8B", asian = "#E0Ac69"
), gender = c(male = "#375b58", female = "#f1bfb6"), vital_status = c(`0` = "#7FFF00", 
`1` = "#FF007F"), age = structure(function (x = NULL, return_rgb = FALSE, 
    max_value = 1) 
{
    if (is.null(x)) {
        stop_wrap("Please specify `x`\n")
    }
    att = attributes(x)
    if (is.data.frame(x)) 
        x = as.matrix(x)
    l_na = is.na(x)
    if (all(l_na)) {
        return(rep(NA, length(l_na)))
    }
    x2 = x[!l_na]
    x2 = ifelse(x2 < breaks[1], breaks[1], ifelse(x2 > breaks[length(breaks)], 
        breaks[length(breaks)], x2))
    ibin = .bincode(x2, breaks, right = TRUE, include.lowest = TRUE)
    res_col = character(length(x2))
    for (i in unique(ibin)) {
        l = ibin == i
        res_col[l] = .get_color(x2[l], breaks[i], breaks[i + 
            1], colors[i, ], colors[i + 1, ], space = space)
    }
    res_col = paste(res_col, transparency_str[1], sep = "")
    if (return_rgb) {
        res_col = t(col2rgb(as.vector(res_col), alpha = TRUE)/255)
        return(res_col)
    }
    else {
        res_col2 = character(length(x))
        res_col2[l_na] = NA
        res_col2[!l_na] = res_col
        attributes(res_col2) = att
        return(res_col2)
    }
}, breaks = c(28, 61, 88), colors = c("#BFE8FFFF", "#7896AAFF", 
"#374C5BFF"), transparency = 0, space = "LAB"), pstage = c(`stage i` = "#ebc7c8", 
`stage ii` = "#b79caf", `stage iii` = "#777893", `stage iv` = "#33576b"
), Subtype = c(`KIRP 2a` = "#e784ba", `KIRP 1a` = "#80e8dd", 
`KIRP 1b` = "#7cc2f6", `KIRP 2b` = "#f9c1a0", `KIRP 1c` = "#af81e4", 
`KIRP 2c` = "#b7f6af"))
```

Comment: The object `cluster` is needed in your case.